# Relation between Homeomorphisms and Isomorphisms for varities.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am right now learning Algebraic Geometry and at the first moment is very demanding. One of my biggest doubts is: why algebraic geometers despise so much **homeomorphisms** , all books that I have been using never make a simple connection with this, in some sense the idea of defining Zariski "TOPOLOGY???" was rather artificial. Finally I found this exercise that made all clear in my mind, but sadly I am unable to solve it:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible quasi-projective varieties. Show that a
>   morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ is
>   a homeomorphism (with respect to the Zariski topology), and for every
>   point $P \in X$ the homomorphism $f^{*}: {O}_{Y,f(p)} \rightarrow
>  {O}_{X,P}$ given by $f^{*}(g) = g \circ f$ is an isomorphism.

I have been using Miles Reid UGA, Shafarevich (cool problems!!!) and some on-line resources (like notes), in none of these sources I have found the word **homeomorphism**, neither they have proven that a morphism is continuous with respect to the so-called Zariski topology.

I apologize for speaking so much nonsenses in the beginning. Please do not misunderstand me, I am enjoying quite a lot Algebraic Geometry!

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Now I come back to this problem to share some thoughts. 
First of all one implication is clear, for the other the strategy that I will try to use is proving that $f^{*}: k(Y) \rightarrow k(X)$ is a k-algebra isomorphism. We know that $f^{*}$ is a well defined homomorphism since $f$ is a morphism, then we have to prove that $f^{*}$ is bijective.

- Now $Ker \; f^{*} = {0}$, because $f^{*}(g) = 0$ with $g \in k(Y)$ implies that $g \circ f \equiv 0$ and using that f is a **homeomorphism** we get that $g$ is necessarily the zero function. Then $f^{*}$ is injective.
- Let $\phi$ be any function in $k(X)$, then we want to find some $g \in k(Y)$ such that $f^{*}(g) = \phi$, that is $g \circ f = \phi$. Using that $f$ is a **homeomorphism** we have that there is a unique function $g$ defined as $g = \phi \circ f^{-1}$ that satisfy the previous restriction (at this point we cannot say that $g \in k(Y)$). Now there is some $P \in X$ such that $\phi$ is rational at $P$, that is $\phi \in O_{X, P}$. This last assertion comes from the fact that $\phi \in k(X)$ by definition $\phi = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in k[X]$ and $q \neq 0$. Using the restricted isomorphism $f^{*}: {O}_{Y,f(p)} \rightarrow {O}_{X,P}$, there exists some $g_1 \in {O}_{Y,f(p)}$ such that $f^{*}(g_1) = \phi$ and by the previous uniqueness even as function, we get that $g = g_1$. Then we get $g \in k(Y)$ which do not depend on the chosen point $P$ and $f^{*}$ is also surjective.

I would appreciate if someone could say me if I am making any mistake in this "proof". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that homeomorphisms are not much talked about is because algebraic geometers demand more. Two homeomorphic varieties might not be isomorphic, (eg any two complex tori are homeomorphic, but a complex torus admits many different structures as an algebraic variety). This happens all the time in math. A function between rings might preserves addition (group morphism) but not preserve multiplication (not a ring morphism). The more structure you put on a set, the more chances you have to distinguish two objects, and the more information needs to be preserved by its morphisms.